# Assign each value to object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am taking data from my backend in this simple way

```
this.archiveService.getRooms(team).subscribe(
  res => {
   this.form = res;
    this.form.forEach(el => {
     el.reservation.slice(-6).match(/.{1,2}/g).join('/');
    });

  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
)
```

`this.form` is a Object I am getting reservation number from form then I want to slice everything that I don't want. ( Regex works fine ).
Then I want to assign this prepared value into my `this.form` then I using `*ngFor` in table

How can I assign each value from forEach loop into this.form

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I assign each value from forEach loop into this.form

Comment: Is `this.form` an array? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Maybe you can use the `map` function : `this.form = res.map(el => el.reservation.slice(-6).match(/.{1,2}/g).join('/'));`

Comment: @SurajRao Object

Comment: @RenaudC5 it works but now all my form is only values from regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As read in the documentation, the js `slice` method

> Return A new array containing the extracted elements.

In fact, the slice methods **does not** modifiy the current element of the array

---

To solve your problem, you can either use the `splice` methods which works as the following :

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place. To access part of an array without modifying it, see slice().

```js
this.form.forEach(el => {
     el.reservation.splice(-6).match(/.{1,2}/g).join('/');
    });
```

Or re-assign the value using the `slice` method

```js
this.form.forEach(el => {
     el.reservation = el.reservation.slice(-6).match(/.{1,2}/g).join('/');
    });
```

## Small example of usage

```js
const myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

const returnVal = myArr.slice(0,5)

console.log(`val return by slice : ${returnVal}`)
console.log(`current arr : ${myArr}`)

console.log('------------------')


const myArr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

const returnVal2 = myArr2.splice(0,5)

console.log(`val return by splice : ${returnVal2}`)
console.log(`current arr : ${myArr2}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Propose of `.foreach()` doesn't serve what you want.

However, If you feel the life is quite ordinary and want to do some advance.
Check is out
[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#using_thisarg)